# create an internal file in android but don't in the data programa directory

Tags: android, file

Hi guys, well I want to create an internal file in android but than this
needs not to be created in the default folder of my program `(data/data/package)`, i want to create the file in a folder in the same path where the dcim folder is.

Comment: type 'save file android' on the search box, try a little harder please!!!!.

Comment: I did this, but only find the process to create an internal file in the  default directory

Comment: Sounds like you want to store your file in what Android refers to the as the "External Storage" - even though these days that's usually emulated on top of chips permanently soldered into the phone.

Comment: yes but the tablet do not have a sd card, is for reason.

Answer (score 0):

> i want to create the file in a folder in the same path where the dcim folder is

Use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)` to retrieve this location.

> but the tablet do not have a sd card

So? External storage has not meant "a sd card" in years.

Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal):

> Every Android-compatible device supports a shared "external storage" that you can use to save files. This can be a removable storage media (such as an SD card) or an internal (non-removable) storage.